# Resharper highlights the properties not found in data context data template

Tags: c#, wpf, resharper

I have a little issue here. I declared my datatemplate in the top of a xaml and linked to it in listbox itemtemplate. XAML

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="listTemplate">

            <!--In case we need a click add button -->
            <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="92" LastChildFill="False" Margin="17,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="615" Background="Green" >
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Margin="10,0,614,475"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,42,10,29" Width="70"> Приміщення</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,42,10,29" Width="75"> №</TextBlock>
                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="10,42,10,29" Width="91"> Гамма</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,42,10,29" Width="91" Text="{Binding MonitorGammaCh}"></TextBlock>
                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="10,42,10,29" Width="91"> Нейтрон</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,42,10,29" Width="72" Text="{Binding MonitorNeutronCh}"></TextBlock>

                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <!--</StackPanel>-->
        </DataTemplate>

<TabItem x:Name="MonitorsTab" Background="#617891" >
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="../Resources/radioactive 256X256.png" />
                </TabItem.Header>
                <ListBox x:Name="MonitorsList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listTemplate}">

                </ListBox>               
            </TabItem>
```

In my code behind I have

```
 MonitorsTab.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel.MonitorsTabViewModel;


        MonitorsViewModels = new ObservableCollection<MonitorViewModel>
        {
            new MonitorViewModel { MonitorGammaCh = "gamma1", MonitorNeutronCh = "neutron2" } ,
            new MonitorViewModel { MonitorGammaCh = "gamma1", MonitorNeutronCh = "neutron2" }, 
            //new MonitorViewModel { MonitorGammaCh = "gamma1", MonitorNeutronCh = "neutron2"}

        };
        MonitorsList.ItemsSource = MonitorsViewModels;
```

And the result I have is this. No gamma1 and neutron2 text is visible
[image]

I would like to know why does Resharper cannot find the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't infer DataContext from the code-behind. You need to explicitly set design-time DataContext with `d:DataContext` attribute in your XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApplication1:MainWindowViewModel}">
</Window>
```

Once you set it, ReSharper will resolve any DataContext related symbols and will provide you IntelliSense, navigation and other features.